# Unable to acquire security key[s] on mongodb cluster

Tags: mongodb, docker, macos, docker-compose

i have a MongoDB cluster on my MacBook m1 with the following docker-compose :

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  mongodb1:
    image: mongo
    container_name: auths_mongodb1
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok; exit()' | mongosh --host localhost:27017 -u root -p root --quiet
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - "10100:27017"
    command: mongod --replSet rs0 --config /etc/mongod.conf
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mongodb/r1/data/db:/data/db
      - ./docker/mongodb/r1/data/configdb:/data/configdb
      - ./docker/mongodb/r1/keys:/keys
      - ./docker/mongodb/r1/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  mongodb2:
    image: mongo
    container_name: auths_mongodb2
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok; exit()' | mongosh --host localhost:27017 -u root -p root --quiet
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    ports:
      - "10101:27017"
    command: mongod --replSet rs0 --config /etc/mongod.conf
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mongodb/r2/data/db:/data/db
      - ./docker/mongodb/r2/data/configdb:/data/configdb
      - ./docker/mongodb/r2/keys:/keys
      - ./docker/mongodb/r2/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  mongodb3:
    image: mongo
    container_name: auths_mongodb3
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok; exit()' | mongosh --host localhost:27017 -u root -p root --quiet
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    ports:
      - "10102:27017"
    command: mongod --replSet rs0 --config /etc/mongod.conf
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mongodb/r3/data/db:/data/db
      - ./docker/mongodb/r3/data/configdb:/data/configdb
      - ./docker/mongodb/r3/keys:/keys
      - ./docker/mongodb/r3/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

 # this container will exit after executing the command
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:5.0
    container_name: auths_mongodb
    restart: 'no'
    command: >
      mongosh --host auths_mongodb1:27017 -u root -p root --eval
      '
      config = {
      "_id" : "rs0",
      "members" : [
        {
          "_id" : 0,
          "host" : "auths_mongodb1:27017"
        },
        {
          "_id" : 1,
          "host" : "auths_mongodb2:27017"
        },
        {
          "_id" : 2,
          "host" : "auths_mongodb3:27017"
        }
      ]
      };
      rs.initiate(config);
      '
    depends_on:
      - mongodb1
      - mongodb2
      - mongodb3
```

and I created KeyFile with the following command :

```
openssl rand -base64 756
```

but after i start the docker compose it throws error with do not run the cluster.
error is following below :

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-07T07:39:30.505+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-07T07:39:30.507+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-07T07:39:30.508+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-07T07:39:30.513+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20254,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Read security file failed","attr":{"error":{"code":30,"codeName":"InvalidPath","errmsg":"error opening file: /keys/keyFile: bad file"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-07T07:39:30.514+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":5847201, "ctx":"main","msg":"Balancer command scheduler stop requested"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-07T07:39:30.514+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-07T07:39:30.514+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20575,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Error creating service context","attr":{"error":"Location5579201: Unable to acquire security key[s]"}}
```

i permitted keyfile with the 600 and 400 but stills get this error .
how i can fix this issue ?

Comment: Maybe a typo in filename?

Comment: I have the very same problem but on linux. have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The container application sees the key file differently of the host.

You must grant the same permissions for the key file on the container folder, even you have granted it on host.

After create the key file using:

```
openssl rand -base64 756 > /path/to/key/file
```

Grant, on the host, permission for the file:

```
chmod 400 /path/to/key/file
```

So, before you run the *mongod* command on the *docker-compose.yml* file, assure that the key file has the same permissions of the host file on the container volume, running the *chmod* and *chown* commands.

Here is an example (*mongodb-key* is the key file):

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:6.0.13-jammy
        command:
             - /bin/sh
             - -c
             - |
              chmod 400 /keys/mongodb-key
              chown 999:999 /keys/mongodb-key
              mongod --replSet rs0 --keyFile /keys/mongodb-key --bind_ip_all
        container_name: mongodb
        environment:
          MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "YOUR_USER"
          MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "YOUR_PASSWORD"
        restart: on-failure
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"
        volumes:
          - /path/to/key/dir:/keys
          - /path/to/data/dir:/data/db
```